# Rotation3DEffect having undesired effect on Text

Tags: swiftui

**How is this problem different from other animation questions**: I have not seen any articles addressing reversed Text. Please see below:

[image: Text]

Here is the code that causes this:

```
 .rotation3DEffect(
            .init(degrees: isTapped ? 180 : 0),
            axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0),
            anchor: .center,
            anchorZ: 20.0,
            perspective: 1.0
        )
```

**Here is how I tried to resolve:** :

1. Tried to replace 180º with 360º which of course made the card spin twice (undesired but rendered the text straight)
2. Tried to use .reversed() as a workaround
3. Played with all of the params of 3DEffect to no avail
4. Searched internet for solution, no answer to this specific problem

**Edit** Also if anyone knows why the text renders like that when going back to arabic view.. that would be great additional assistance.

**Edit** Adding example code, able to just copy and paste and go

**Edit** Another edit, forgot I tried to use .reversed() as a workaround

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let grid = [GridItem(.fixed(100), spacing: 5, alignment: .center),
                GridItem(.fixed(100), spacing: 5, alignment: .center),
                GridItem(.fixed(100), spacing: 5, alignment: .center)]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LazyVGrid(columns: grid, content: {
                ForEach(Example.example, id: \.name) { ex in
                    AnimatedView(data: ex)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct Example {
    let name: String
    let translation: String
    
    static let example =
        [Example(name: "First", translation: "Second"),
         Example(name: "Third", translation: "Fourth"),
         Example(name: "Fifth", translation: "Sixth"),
         Example(name: "Seventh", translation: "Eigth"),
         Example(name: "Ninth", translation: "Tenth"),
         Example(name: "Eleventh", translation: "Twelth")
        ]
}

struct AnimatedView: View {
    @State private var isTapped = false
    
    let data: Example
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {self.isTapped.toggle()}) {
            Text(isTapped ? data.name : data.translation)
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 100)
                .background(isTapped ? Color.blue : .black)
                .cornerRadius(8)
        }.rotation3DEffect(
            .init(degrees: isTapped ? 180 : 0),
            axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0),
            anchor: .center,
            anchorZ: 0,
            perspective: 0
        )
        .animation(.linear)
    }
}
```

Comment: would u add some reproduce-able code?

Comment: @Yodagama Yes, apologies, I just added. Can insert that right into Xcode

Comment: Worth considering to make it via separated component, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60808061/12299030.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
struct AnimatedView: View {
    @State private var isTapped = false
    
    let data: Example
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {self.isTapped.toggle()}) {
            Text(isTapped ? data.name : data.translation)
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 100)
                .background(isTapped ? Color.blue : .black)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .rotation3DEffect( //<- here
                    .init(degrees: isTapped ? 180 : 0),
                    axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0),
                    anchor: .center,
                    anchorZ: 0,
                    perspective: 0
                )        }.rotation3DEffect(
            .init(degrees: isTapped ? 180 : 0),
            axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0),
            anchor: .center,
            anchorZ: 0,
            perspective: 0
        )
        .animation(.linear)
    }
}
```

Comment: we can use Animatable data to better rotation effect like real card !

Comment: Would love to see a brief example if possible or a good reference